# Trigger Class Function Call from Tab Navigator Tab Press - React Native/Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, tabs, react-navigation

I have a TabNavigator component and I want the individual Tab Screen state to get reset on a tab press. How do I call a class (component) method on a tab press? I've looked at tabBarOnPress, but this takes a function from the parent level (TabNavigator). I want the class method to be triggered and I don't want to export that method.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you have TabNavigator like this

```js
const HOME = TabNavigator({
  [SCREENS.EXPLORESCREEN]: { screen: ExploreScreen },
  [SCREENS.ASKSCREEN]: { screen: AskScreen },
  },{
        initialRouteName: SCREENS.EXPLORESCREEN
    })
  const PrimaryNav = StackNavigator({
  [SCREENS.HOMESCREEN]: {
    screen: HOME,
    navigationOptions=({navigation})=>{
    return{
          tabBarOnPress :()=>{ 
            if (typeof navigation.state.params.cancelState!=="undefined"){
                 navigation.state.params.cancelState()
            }
            else{
            //your stuff
            }
           }   
      }
    }
  },
},
  {
    // Default config for all screens
    headerMode: "screen",
    initialRouteName: SCREENS.HOMESCREEN
    ,

  }

);
```

ExploreScreen.js

```js
class ExploreScreen extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
    cancelState:this.cancelState
    })

  }
  cancelState=()=>{
  //your Stuff
  }
}
```

- you can use navigationOptions in component level as well.

Comment: Not bad, thanks! One case to watch out for is when a tab is a stackNavigator. In that case, you have to access state.routes before getting to params. Also, a small typo where navigationOptions should be followed by a ":" rather than a "=". Any other solutions?

Comment: Wish i could upvote multiple times, Spent hours on this. Thank you